# Location of DIV that display MySQL within PHP file

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

Ok so I have this below page, it pulls back some details from a DB. The final line shows me how many rows I have with a certain state.

My issue I want to show this at the top of the page not the bottom, if I copy my last line to the top it doesnt count correctly and just shows 1 rather than 2 currently as it does at the bottom. Any ideas how I can include this final  div at the top but have it dispaly the correct output?

Any help would be really useful.

```
 <h2>All P1 Issues</h2>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-head-bordered-bottom table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class=span1>Ticket ID</th>
  <th class=span2>Title</th>
  <th class=span2>Submitter</th>
  <th class=span2>Owner</th>
  <th class=span2>Status</th>
  <th class=span1>Created</th>
  <th class=span1>Modified</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>

<?php

$query1 = "
SELECT HD_TICKET.ID as ID, 
HD_TICKET.TITLE as Title, 
HD_STATUS.NAME AS Status, 
HD_PRIORITY.NAME AS Priority, 
HD_TICKET.CREATED as Created, 
HD_TICKET.MODIFIED as Modified, 
S.FULL_NAME  as Submitter, 
O.FULL_NAME  as Owner, 
HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 as Type  
FROM HD_TICKET  
JOIN HD_STATUS ON (HD_STATUS.ID = HD_TICKET.HD_STATUS_ID) 
JOIN HD_PRIORITY ON (HD_PRIORITY.ID = HD_TICKET.HD_PRIORITY_ID) 
LEFT JOIN USER S ON (S.ID = HD_TICKET.SUBMITTER_ID) 
LEFT JOIN USER O ON (O.ID = HD_TICKET.OWNER_ID) 
WHERE HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID IN( 1,3) AND 
(HD_PRIORITY.NAME like '%High%') OR
(HD_STATUS.NAME like '%Critical%')
ORDER BY Owner, Created DESC
";


$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
$num = mysql_numrows($result1);
$i = 0;
  while ($i < $num)
{
$ID = mysql_result($result1,$i,"ID");
$Title = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Title");
$Status = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Status");        
$Type = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Type");
$Created = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Created");
$Modified = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Modified");
$Priority = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Priority");
$Owner = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Owner"); 
$Submitter = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Submitter");


$ID = stripslashes($ID);
$Title = stripslashes($Title);
$Status = stripslashes($Status);
$Type = stripslashes($Type);
$Created = stripslashes($Created);  
$Modified = stripslashes($Modified);
$Priority = stripslashes($Priority);
$Owner = stripslashes($Owner);
$Submitter = stripslashes($Submitter);



$StatusSpan="";
if ($Status=="Stalled")
{
    $StatusSpan="<span class='label label-warning'>$Status</span>";
}

$PriortySpan="";
if ($Priority=="High")
{
    $PriortySpan="<span class='label label-important'><i class='icon-exclamation-sign icon-white'></i>High</span>";
}

if ($Priority=="Low")
{
    $PriortySpan="<span class='label'>Low</span>";
}

if ($Priority=="Medium")
{
    $PriortySpan="<span class='label'>Medium</span>";
}

if ($Priority=="Critical")
{
    $PriortySpan="<span class='label'><i class='icon-exclamation-sign icon-white'></i>Critical</span>";
}



echo "<tr><td><a href='http://$KaceBoxDNS/adminui/ticket.php?ID=$ID' target='_blank'>$ID</a>     $StatusSpan $PriortySpan</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Title</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Submitter</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Owner</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Status</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Created</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Modified</td> \n";
echo "</tr> \n";
$i++;
}

echo "<p><span class='label label-important'>$num P1 Issues</span></p>"; 
echo "</tbody></table> \n";
?>
 <center><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>No Current</strong><?php  echo "<p><span class='label label-important'>$num P1 Issues</span></p>"; ?>  Critical / High Priority Incidents</div></center>
```

Comment: did you put the processing code above the "final div"

Comment: Try moving the entire `<?php ... ?>` before all the html markup.

Comment: Alo stop using mysql_* functions the are deprecated. Start using mysqli_* and PDO instead..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hop in & out of PHP in an HTML code.

Below is an example of this.
Also in HTML you can use `<br>` or `<br />` as `/n` is used in texts to break line. A last point: `mysql*` is deprecated, I'd advise using `PDO` instead, as it's great fun.

```
<?php

$query1 = "
SELECT HD_TICKET.ID as ID, 
HD_TICKET.TITLE as Title, 
HD_STATUS.NAME AS Status, 
HD_PRIORITY.NAME AS Priority, 
HD_TICKET.CREATED as Created, 
HD_TICKET.MODIFIED as Modified, 
S.FULL_NAME  as Submitter, 
O.FULL_NAME  as Owner, 
HD_TICKET.CUSTOM_FIELD_VALUE0 as Type  
FROM HD_TICKET  
JOIN HD_STATUS ON (HD_STATUS.ID = HD_TICKET.HD_STATUS_ID) 
JOIN HD_PRIORITY ON (HD_PRIORITY.ID = HD_TICKET.HD_PRIORITY_ID) 
LEFT JOIN USER S ON (S.ID = HD_TICKET.SUBMITTER_ID) 
LEFT JOIN USER O ON (O.ID = HD_TICKET.OWNER_ID) 
WHERE HD_TICKET.HD_QUEUE_ID IN( 1,3) AND 
(HD_PRIORITY.NAME like '%High%') OR
(HD_STATUS.NAME like '%Critical%')
ORDER BY Owner, Created DESC
";


$result1 = mysql_query($query1);
$num = mysql_numrows($result1);
$i = 0;
  while ($i < $num)
{
$ID = mysql_result($result1,$i,"ID");
$Title = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Title");
$Status = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Status");        
$Type = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Type");
$Created = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Created");
$Modified = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Modified");
$Priority = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Priority");
$Owner = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Owner"); 
$Submitter = mysql_result($result1,$i,"Submitter");


$ID = stripslashes($ID);
$Title = stripslashes($Title);
$Status = stripslashes($Status);
$Type = stripslashes($Type);
$Created = stripslashes($Created);  
$Modified = stripslashes($Modified);
$Priority = stripslashes($Priority);
$Owner = stripslashes($Owner);
$Submitter = stripslashes($Submitter);



$StatusSpan="";
if ($Status=="Stalled")
{
    $StatusSpan="<span class='label label-warning'>$Status</span>";
}

$PriortySpan="";
if ($Priority=="High")
{
    $PriortySpan="<span class='label label-important'><i class='icon-exclamation-sign     icon-white'></i>High</span>";
}

if ($Priority=="Low")
{
    $PriortySpan="<span class='label'>Low</span>";
}

if ($Priority=="Medium")
{
    $PriortySpan="<span class='label'>Medium</span>";
}

if ($Priority=="Critical")
{
    $PriortySpan="<span class='label'><i class='icon-exclamation-sign icon-white'>        </i>Critical</span>";
}

?>
<h2>All P1 Issues</h2>
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-head-bordered-bottom table-condensed">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class=span1>Ticket ID</th>
  <th class=span2>Title</th>
  <th class=span2>Submitter</th>
  <th class=span2>Owner</th>
  <th class=span2>Status</th>
  <th class=span1>Created</th>
  <th class=span1>Modified</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
<?php

/* THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART FOR YOUR STUFF */

echo "<tr><td><a href='http://$KaceBoxDNS/adminui/ticket.php?ID=$ID' target='_blank'>$ID</a>     $StatusSpan $PriortySpan</td> \n";
echo "<td>$Title</td><br>";
echo "<td>$Submitter</td><br>";
echo "<td>$Owner</td><br>";
echo "<td>$Status</td><br>";
echo "<td>$Created</td><br>";
echo "<td>$Modified</td><br>";
echo "</tr> \n";
$i++;
}

?>

 <tbody>
 <?php 

 echo "<p><span class='label label-important'>$num P1 Issues</span></p>"; 
 echo "</tbody></table><br>";

 ?>

 <center><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert"><strong>No Current</strong><?php  echo "<p><span class='label label-important'>$num P1 Issues</span></p>"; ?>  Critical / High Priority Incidents</div></center>
```

Comment: Just a side note, would there be anyway to only show that DIV if there are results in that query?

Comment: Like: ````<?php if($result1) { ?> <div id="showTrue"></div> <?php } ?>````